# Make emit be mandatory on Vue for composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I've created a Vue SFC component and I'd like to force defining the event handleClose.

This is the sample code I have now:

```js
// this is Component.vue
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: "handleClose"): void;
}>();

type Props = { isOpen: boolean };
defineProps<Props>();
```

If I try to use `<Component />`, I get an error about not having prop `isOpen`, but it doesn't complain about the missing `@handle-close`.

Is there a way to force this check and show a warning when the `@handle-close` is not defined?

Comment: No. Event listeners are optional by their meaning, also Vue template type checks are lacking. This kind of fool proof looks more like a case for tests rather than comp design.  You can possibly check for the listeners in getCurrentInstance internals but I'm not sure there's something usable

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask! I was passing a function as props, but that seems to not be the Vue way and it's preferable to use emits. I'm really considering the "pass event on props" way instead of this "waste 15min looking for the issue because you missed a character" way :)

Comment: I stand corrected about render function, it's applicable to a related but different case. Yes, you're right about a prop, it's doable but against Vue conventions. There's a lot of ways to make a typo without a warn, so I'd leave these inconsistencies for tests. Notice that events are easily debuggable in Vue devtools on the other hand, while you have to rely on breakpoints for prop function

Comment: It can be a bit hard to test if it's for instance a notification component. Sometimes it's not feasible to test all the places where the component is called and sometimes testing what is being passed to a component is more testing the internals. Which I prefer to avoid

Comment: Can possibly be covered by behaviour tests instead of testing the implementation. IME if you loose time more than once or twice on some kind of mistakes, this can be covered by tests, it possibly is not worth it. Any way, it's technically possible to assert events through internals. Since you rely on them only for development, it looks ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`@foo` event listener is compiled to `onFoo` prop on vnode](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#v-on), this can be asserted on internal component instance:

```
function checkEmits(...eventNames) {
  let props;

  if (import.meta.env.DEV && props = getCurrentInstance()?.vnode.props) {
    for (const name of eventNames) {
      const propName = 'on' + toPascalCase(name);
      if (typeof props[propName] !== 'function')
        console.warn(name + ' event listener is missing');
    }
  }

  return eventNames;
}
```

And used like:

```
const emits = defineEmits(['foo', bar']);
checkEmits('foo');
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now, this seems like a good option. Thank you!